# AWS SaaS Subscription Developer - Monitor for changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace

I developed SaaS subscription process in PHP.
Need PHP module or addition (class) for Monitoring changes.
I need functions like
Setup SQS queue,
subscribe to product's SNS topic
get notifications (subscribe success, unsuccess etc.)

Where I get error?
I created SNS subscribe, subscribed to SNS topic, but for get error.

Caught exception: Error executing "AddPermission" on "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: Sender Authorizati (truncated...) AuthorizationError (client): User: arn:aws:iam::https://forums.aws.amazon.com/:root is not authorized to perform: SNS:AddPermission on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:https://forums.aws.amazon.com/:aws-mp-subscription-notification-https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ - Sender AuthorizationError User: arn:aws:iam::https://forums.aws.amazon.com/:root is not authorized to perform: SNS:AddPermission on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:https://forums.aws.amazon.com/:aws-mp-subscription-notification-https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ http://....

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the [SNS topic provided by AWS Marketplace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/saas-notification.html) to notify your application on when buyers subscribe successfully and unsubscribes, that SNS topic is owned and managed by AWS Marketplace. Thus, certain actions altering the SNS topic attributes may not be available.

Nonetheless, your seller AWS account should already have permission to subscribe to that SNS topic. So using your seller AWS account, you can subscribe HTTP web hooks, emails, SQS queues, etc.

For more info, please see the [SNS topic page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/saas-notification.html) in the AWS Marketplace seller guide for SaaS products.